# Can't get changed select name in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Apologies for this but I'm new with angularjs.

I have a select control and the that is being populated from this markup:

```
<select ng-model="limit" data-ng-options="listLimit.name for listLimit in listLimits" data-ng-change="limitChanged()"></select>
```

Once done the option names are simply 50, 100 & 150.

The problem that I'm having is that when I change the value in the select control, the limitChanged() function doesn't appear to know the new option name selected from the control. For example:

```
module.controller('PageController', function ($scope) {

    // $scopr.listLimits[0] is essentially the object {name:50}
    $scope.limit = $scope.listLimits[0];

    $scope.limitChanged = function() {
        // This will log 50 (the default value) regardless of what's been selected.
        console.log($scope.limit.name);
        loadList(); // This will change the item limit.
    };
}
```

However, in the view, if I put `{{limit}}` somewhere this is updated with the value as the select control is changed. I'm confused. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was actually being caused by a missing `ng-controller` attribute on the surrounding div. I guess this meant that the control didn't fall within the scope of the controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

My be something wrong with  your data(listLimits), For me it works.
See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79pDQ/37/)

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.limitList =[
         { name: "value1"},
         { name: "value2"},
          { name: "value3"}
     ];

    $scope.limit='';

    $scope.limitChanged=function(){
      console.log($scope.limit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've put this in place and it's logging out '50' on page load. Nothing when the control is changed though?